# SSL Implementation for iOS app

Tags: ios, asp.net, api, ssl

I have been developing iOS for years but this is my first time building a backend for an app, so SSL subject matter isn't a strong point for me.

I have installed a SSL certificate on my IIS 8.0 (Server 2012). I have confirmed that the https endpoint is functioning properly.

My question: Is there anything I have to do in my iOS application (using RestKit 0.2 for server communication) other than change the endpoint from http to https?  I'm not sure when I consider the traffic going to the server to be "secure". Bit of a noob question I know but, I don't want to miss something simple on the iOS side and think everything is secure when it is not.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use [OpenSSL](http://serverfault.com/questions/587329/heartbleed-what-is-it-and-what-are-options-to-mitigate-it) :P